# Perl REST call contains special characters

Tags: json, perl, solr

Hi I am calling REST call from Perl to SoLr. Below is the code which contains special characters in search criteria. When i check in the SoLr, the call doesn't receive the complete json string.

```
#!perl -w
use REST::Client;
use JSON;
use MIME::Base64; 
use Redis;

my %Hash;
my %Data; my %Param; my @DataArray;
$Hash{archiveFlag} = '0';
$Param{Parameter} = "some.545";
$Param{SortBy} = "Age";
$Param{OrderBy} = "Up";
$Data{searchType} = "Fulltext";
$Data{parameters} = \%Param;
$DataArray[0] = \%Data;
$Hash{searchConditionWrapper} = \@DataArray;

my $Data = encode_json \%Hash;
print $Data;    
$url="http://localhost:8181/DashboardDAVE/cont/solr"; 
my $headers = {'Accept' => 'application/json', 'Content-Type' => 'application/json'};
my $client = REST::Client->new();
$client->setHost($url);
$client->GET($Data, $headers);
print $client->responseContent();
```

Below is the error.
Exception while parsing json 1:null

Any help on this much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share us the output, when you manually access the *url* in browser?

Comment: Your output shows `500 internal server error`.  It is also showing the undefined `content-type` in header. Please solve those problem and re-attempt again.

Comment: Update the code `use utf;`

Comment: What do you mean by "special characters"?

Comment: @ssr1012: I don't know of a "utf" pragma, so that's probably going to give a syntax error. It's possible that you meant `use utf8;` but I can't see how that will help as there don't appear to be any non-ASCII characters in the source code.

Comment: the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/REST::Client) seems to show that `setHost()` parameter should be just the actual host: `http://localhost:8081`, then in the `GET` call, the first parameter should be the rest of the URL (`DashboardDAVE/cont/solr`), followed by your other arguments. I have no clue if this is causing your problem, but it's likely worth trying an example as per the docs.

Comment: `What do you mean by "special characters"?` Since I said to use `utf8`.

Comment: My point is that "special characters" is a pretty meaningless phrase. I guess that to most people it means "non-ASCII characters". But in that case, you need to know what character encoding you are using in order to give any kind of meaningful answer. And `use utf8` is only of use if your **source code** contains UTF8-encoded characters - which it clearly doesn't here.

Comment: special characters like ".", "#", "@" etc.or it might be foreign languages

Comment: Why are those characters special? They look like pretty standard ASCII characters to me.

Comment: But because of which the complete (JSON) data is not received at the  SOLR side. It breaks at the character ('#'/'.'). If i remove these characters and make a call it works correctly.

Comment: I think he is stating that JSON encoding isnt working, or it is improperly encoding and on the SOLR side it cant be decoded? Can you provide a dump of your JSON string at least that is created on your end?

Comment: `{"searchConditionWrapper":[{"parameters":{"SortBy":"Age","Parameter":"Some.545","Orde
rBy":"Up"},"searchType":"Fulltext"},{"parameters":{"SortBy":"Age","Parameter":"1
,4,10","OrderBy":"Up"},"searchType":"State"}],"archiveFlag":"0"}`